# Java program works but ends early

Tags: java

I have a program that I am writing that has these directions:

- When creating the 10 Taxpayer objects, increment the SSN by 10 and their income by 10,000;
- starting at 10 and 10,000 respectively.
- The output should look like
- Taxpayer SSN: 10 Income: 10000
- Taxpayer SSN: 20 Income: 20000
- ...
- Taxpayer SSN: 100 Income: 100000

I have the code written but am getting it to end at 90 instead of 100.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class UseTaxpayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Taxpayer[] tp = new Taxpayer[10];
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            payer[i] = new Taxpayer(i*10, 10000*i);
            System.out.println("Taxpayer SSN: " + payer[i].getSS() + " Income: " + tp[i].getIncome());
        }
    }
} 

class Taxpayer {
    private int socialsecurity, income;

    Taxpayer(int ss, int income) {
        socialsecurity = ss;
        this.income = income;
    }

    int getSS() {
        return socialsecurity;
    }

    int getIncome() {
        return income;
    }
}
```

I have "kludged" a working solution with doing this for the For statement:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            payer[i] = new payer(i * 10 + 10, (10000 * (i + 1))); // calculates the SSN and money based upon directions
            System.out.println(" Taxpayer SSN: " + payer[i].getSSN()
                    + " Income: " + payer[i].getmoney());

If I start the array at 1, I get an off by one error.  If I don't add the "+ 10" section of payer(i), I get SSN: 0  Income 10000.

This method works but wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 4):

Use <= instead of < in your for loop.

Comment: When I do this, I get this as an output in Eclipse - Taxpayer SSN: 10 Income: 10000
 Taxpayer SSN: 20 Income: 20000
 Taxpayer SSN: 30 Income: 30000
 Taxpayer SSN: 40 Income: 40000
 Taxpayer SSN: 50 Income: 50000
 Taxpayer SSN: 60 Income: 60000
 Taxpayer SSN: 70 Income: 70000
 Taxpayer SSN: 80 Income: 80000
 Taxpayer SSN: 90 Income: 90000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at UseTaxpayer.main(UseTaxpayer.java:34)

Comment: I put an update to my original post showing how I fixed the code but wonder if it could be done better.  I was getting errors if I used <= for the for statement.  If I started the array at 0, the output would start as SSN: 0 Income: 10000 instead of SSN: 10 Income 10000.

Comment: The line:Taxpayer[] tp = new Taxpayer[10];

Comment: The line: "Taxpayer[] tp = new Taxpayer[10];" created a 10-element index with index references 0-9. I see you already figured out to change your multipliers from i to i+1. An alternative would have been to make the array with 11 elements instead, 0-10, and not use the one with the 0 reference. A 3rd option would have been to use a separate multiplier: multiplier = i+1. That might have helped with readability. Each of those 3 options has very minor pros and cons - I wouldn't say one is "best" unless you're turning this in for a grade and your prof has specific preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. The only thing you're missing is when you say i<10, this doesn't include 10. This can be fixed by saying i<=10, or i<11.

Answer (score 0):

You are having an off-by-one error in your `for` loop.  If you change the `i<10` to `i<=10`, it will solve your problem.

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
   tp[i]=new Taxpayer(i*10,(10000*i));
   System.out.println(" Taxpayer SSN:" + tp[i].getSS()+" Income: "+tp[i].getIncome());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit easier to read you could do:

```
    for(int i=10;i<=100;i = i + 10){ 
        tp[i] = new Taxpayer(i, 1000*i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your loop only has 9 iterations. Make the check less than or equal to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    Taxpayer[] tp = new Taxpayer[11];

    for (int i=1; i<=11; i++) {
        tp[i] = new Taxpayer(i*10, (10000*i));
        System.out.println("Taxpayer SSN: " + tp[i].getSS() + " Income: " +
```